# how to use json_encode to update data in a foreach?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

i have a foreach looping through messages for the logged in user and displayng them listSuccess.php:

```
$cursor = $pager->getFirstIndice(); 
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $msg)
{ 
$unique_code_from = $msg->getRcProfileTableRelatedByProfileIdFrom()->getUniqueCode();
$block_url = link_to('Block User',"blocklist/block?unqiue_code=$unique_code_from",'class=link_medium_blue');

echo "<tr id='td_id' value='.$cursor.'>";
    $date = add_date($msg->getCreatedAt(),$hr=2);
echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_date'>".$date."</td>";
    $opened_once = $msg->getOpenedOnce();
    <td align='left' id='td_subject'>
       <a href="<?php echo url_for('messagebox/read?cursor=').$cursor ?>" style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'><?php echo $msg->getSubject();?></a>
    </td>
    <?php
      echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_from'>".$unique_code_from."  </td>";
      echo "<td>( ".$block_url." )</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      ++$cursor; 
 }
```

i have a tag for date: td_date,subject: td_subject and who the message is from:td_from
then i have my actions.class.php

```
 public function executeNewMessageDetails(sfWebRequest $request)
 {   

    $profile_id = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('profile_id','zero');  
    $new_msgs = RcMessageBoxTablePeer::getNewMessages($profile_id);
    foreach ($new_msgs as $row)
    {
       $date = $row->getCreatedAt();
       $subject = $row->getSubject();
       $from = $row->getProfileIdFrom();
       $id = $row->getId();
       $uc_record = RcProfileTablePeer::getById($from);
       $uc_from = $uc_record->getUniqueCode();
       //$block_url = 'Block User',"blocklist/block?unqiue_code=$uc_from",'class=link_medium_blue');
    }
    $output = array("td_date" => $date, "td_subject" => $subject, "td_from" => $uc_from, "td_id" => $id);
    return $this->renderText(json_encode($output));
}
```

then the JS:

```
function ax_get_new_msg_details()
{
   var mTimer; 
   mTimer = setTimeout('ax_get_new_msg_details();',30000);
   $.getJSON('/apps_dev.php/messagebox/newMessageDetails', function(data) 
{
    var td_id = $('#td_id');
    var str='<tr>';
    str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_date'>"+data.td_date+'</td>';
    str += "<td align='left' id='td_subject'><a href='#' style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'>"+data.td_subject+"</a></td>";
    str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_from'>"+data.td_from +"</td>";
    //str += "<td id='block_url'>"+data.block_url+"</td>";
    str +='<tr>';
    var tbl = $('#td_date').parents('table');
    if (td_id == data.td_id)
    {

    }
    else
    {
       $(tbl).append(str);
    }   
});
}
```

it runs fine BUT it replaces the first message in the foreach list with the new one, i want my code to add to the end of the list thus displaying the new entry at the end of the list. how can i achieve this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function ax_get_new_msg_details()
{
   var mTimer; 
   mTimer = setTimeout('ax_get_new_msg_details();',30000);
   $.getJSON('/apps_dev.php/messagebox/newMessageDetails', function(data) 
{
    var str='<tr>';
     str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_date'>"+data.td_date+'</td>';
    str += "<td align='left' id='td_subject'>
       <a href='#' style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'>
    "+data.td_subject+"</a></td>";
    str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_from'>"+data.td_from +"  </td><td>block url</td>";
    str +='<tr>';

   var tbl = $('#td_date').parents('table');

  $(tbl).append(str);

   });
}
```

Comment: thank you it looks like it is working well except it is repeating the whole thing thus RE-displaying the incoming message over and over?? i need to display the new message only once please?
thank you

Comment: you can add $cursor on your <tr id="row_$cursor"> and keep this order at ajax update conditionaly.

Comment: sorry but not sure what you mean? i've never done this stuff sorry can you elaborate please? thank you... please see code added to the top if im on the right path :)